# How to revert xcode pull request?

Tags: xcode, git, github, pull-request

This is my problem and i tried to look solution, didn't find anything related to me.

created new project 1 —> and pushed to github.com (this project is dummy has no code)
created new project 2 —> wrote code and tried pushing to github.com with remote link to project 1 it gave me an error stating to 1st use pull the request. I did pull request.

now the project 2 became empty (which took 2 days to code) is there any option to get back my code?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very strange situation. You shouldn't have been able to do what you describe.
Simulating what you describe in Xcode 8.0, I get a `The remote repository could no be found - make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and try again.` message, because the projects are different.

Maybe something else happened.

Nevertheless, may this be a lesson to you. Commit locally first and then to the remote. You can do both, one after the other, with one operation in Xcode, by checking the `Push to Remote` box in the commit screen. That way you would still have your local code. ;-)